# C# marshal native sized unsigned integer size_t, retrieve value via ref/out parameter

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, marshalling, size-t

I have C# code that calls to a C function exported from native dll (DllImport) .

I want the C code to modify a value of `x` parameter passed from C# and to use modified value in managed code. C function has to be a void returning function. C# code:

```
uint x=0;
Func(x);
```

C code:

```
void Func(size_t x)
{
   x=8;
}
```

I tried:

```
 [DllImport("1.dll")]
 public static extern void Func(size_t x);
```

But after the C# calls `Func` var `x` is still 0. I also tried the following C code. But it doesn't work either. What is my error?

```
void Func(size_t* x)
{
   x=8;
}
```

Comment: if I am not mistaken how are you expected to return x=8 from a `void` method can you change the return type of the c function to return the correct datatype..?

Comment: Read about pointers and references.

Comment: The c code does not modify the value passed in, it modifies a copy only.

Comment: @tkausl i read , see my edit , i not success

Comment: @MethodMan i dont want to return with return , i want to change the parameter value

Comment: I would suggest you read / do a quick google search on the following `C# stackoverflow calling c external dll` there are plenty of posted examples as well as how to can the external method using the `Marshal` key word

Comment: new version changes a copy of a pointer, still doesn't change the value you want it to. try *x = 8;

Comment: You need to use a `ref` parameter on the C# side to do this. I wouldn't recommend it but that's what you need.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen why you dont recommend  on ref?  and i tried ref, that not help

Answer (score 2):

Your example has several problems which have to be solved to get it working as expected. First of all your goal as I understand it is to retrieve value of a C type `size_t` which is set in a C void returning function via parameter.

First simple problem of retrieving value via parameters is solved with help of using either pointers to values in both C# and C or by using a combination of C# parameter modifier (`ref` or `out`) which would enforce passing of C# parameter as a pointer and a pointer in C. The function signatures will be as follows:

```
// Implementation with pointers
[DllImport("MyC.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, PreserveSig = true, EntryPoint = "Func")]
public static extern unsafe void CSharpFuncPtr(UIntPtr* x);

// Implementation with parameter modifiers - ref can be raplaced by out
[DllImport("MyC.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, PreserveSig = true, EntryPoint = "Func")]
public static extern void CSharpFuncMod(ref UIntPtr x);   // 

// C function implementation
void Func(size_t* x) { *x = 7; }
```

The second even more important problem which has to be solved during marshalling is the use of native sized unsigned integer `size_t` as C type. It is defined as either 32bit unsigned integer on x86 architectures or 64bit unsigned integer on x64 architectures (I do intentionally skip all other processor architectures). In .NET type system native sized integral types are missing. The workaround is to use managed unsigned pointer type `UIntPtr` to emulate `size_t` in managed type system.

.NET team is aware of this limitations and there are discussions and plans on implementing so called native integers - see: [Support natural size data types in the CLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/963)

```
[DllImport("MyC.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, PreserveSig = true, EntryPoint = "Func")]
public static extern void CSharpFuncNativeInt(ref nuint x);
```

Finally the problem which seems to be easy at the surface is not that simple after all and simple and elegant solution requires even .NET runtime and BCL libraries changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pointers to and from unmanaged code, you need to use the ref qualifier.

Like:

```
[DllImport("1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Func(ref int x);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int value = 0;
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(value, GCHandleType.Pinned);

    Func(ref value);

    handle.Free();

    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

external code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Func(int * nStatus)
{
    *nStatus = 10;
}
```

This is because in c# you normally can't use pointers, because of the memory management (aka GC). You have to "force it" using ref-s, or unsafe code.

P.S.

It works without the GCHandle.Alloc function, but without that, there is a possibility, that while you are doing work in the unmanaged code the GC moves the value, and it gets corrupted. In this case you don't need it, but if you use a reference type instead of a value type (class instead of struct), than it becomes extremely useful.

Comment: why do you use int and not size_t?